# Using styled span element to highlight word

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the DOM elements with the relevant content (the word 'Test') from a particular webpage, get the content, and finally surround it with a styled span element with the following code. However it is not getting executed. Am I using the documentquery selectorAll the right way? Thank you in advance

```
const $matchedElements = document.querySelectorAll();

$matchedElements.forEach(($element) => {
  if ($element.innerHTML.match("Test")) {
    const $mySpan = document.createElement("span");
    $mySpan.style = "background-color:yellow";
    $mySpan.innerHTML = $element.innerHTML;

    $element.innerHTML = ""
    $element.appendChild($mySpan)
  }
});
```

Comment: BTW, this is exactly what the `<mark>` element has been made for

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rbuljan/hilite

Comment: When you `querySelectorAll` and you iterate over all elements, the `$element.innerHTML.match("Test")` part will be truthy for every parent that contains "Test". Also, `querySelectorAll` requires the selector argument, so you'll need "*" to match all elements.

Answer (score 0):

`<mark>` is an inline element that by default has a yellow background that's semantic as well (it's purpose is to highlight text).

In the example are two functions if you want to target multiple elements then use `collect()`. If you are targeting one element then use `hiLite()`. `hiLite()` is capable of highlighting every given word on a page just by targeting `document.body`, but it can't target a specific group of elements iteratively. `collect()` is designed to help `hiLite()` to target multiple elements iteratively.

```js
document.forms.UI.onsubmit = search;

function search(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const IO = this.elements;
  let term = IO.search.value;
  const main = document.querySelector('main');
  hiLite(term, main);
};


/**
 * @desc Find all occurrences of a given word of a given DOM object
 * (HTMLElement) and warp each matched word in a <mark>
 * @param {string} term - A string being searched for
 * @param {object<DOM>} node - An element referenced as a DOM object
 * @default {object<DOM>} node - If undefined it will be document.body
 */
function hiLite(term, node = document.body) {
  const str = node.innerHTML;
  const newStr = str.split(' ').flatMap(
      word => word.toLowerCase() == term.toLowerCase() ?
      `<mark>${word}</mark>` : word)
    .join(' ');
  node.replaceChildren();
  node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newStr);
}

/**
 * @desc Iterate through a NodeList and run a function (callback) on each  
 * node. This function is a helper function for hiLite(). While hiLite()  
 * is capable of highlighting a whole page, it lacks the ability to highlight 
 * specific elements iteratively.
 * @param {string<CSS selector>} selector - The targeted elements
 * @param {string} term - A string being searched for
 * @param {function} callback - A function to run on each iteration
 */
function collect(selector, term, callback) {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  nodes.forEach(node => callback(term, node));
}

collect('p', 'Force', hiLite);
```

```html
<form id='UI'>
  <input id='search' type='search'><button>Search</button>
</form>
<main>
  <p>Remember, a Jedi can feel the Force flowing through him. Don't underestimate the Force. Obi-Wan is here. The Force is with him. In my experience, there is no such thing as luck. Red Five standing by.</p>
  <p>As you wish. I'm surprised you had the courage to take the responsibility yourself. Oh God, my uncle. How am I ever gonna explain this? The more you tighten your grip, Tarkin, the more star systems will slip through your fingers.</p>
  <p>I have traced the Rebel spies to her. Now she is my only link to finding their secret base. All right. Well, take care of yourself, Han. I guess that's what you're best at, ain't it? I'm surprised you had the courage to take the responsibility yourself.</p>
  <p>But with the blast shield down, I can't even see! How am I supposed to fight? She must have hidden the plans in the escape pod. Send a detachment down to retrieve them, and see to it personally, Commander. There'll be no one to stop us this time!</p>
  <p>Dantooine. They're on Dantooine. Remember, a Jedi can feel the Force flowing through him. Don't act so surprised, Your Highness. You weren't on any mercy mission this time. Several transmissions were beamed to this ship by Rebel spies. I want to know
    what happened to the plans they sent you.</p>
  <p>Don't be too proud of this technological terror you've constructed. The ability to destroy a planet is insignificant next to the power of the Force. All right. Well, take care of yourself, Han. I guess that's what you're best at, ain't it?</p>
</main>
```

Comment: This is a straightforward but pretty dangerous approach. 1. will not work with a search input - which will operate on an already altered HTML. 2. innerHTML should not be used. 3. you should never pass unescaped arbitrary match strings into `RegExp`.

Comment: 1. Just added the search input and an event handler. I didn't see any mention of how this highlighting would be implemented or anything about a search input. Also, the functions can target anything on the page. 2. `.innerHTML` is used to read not to write, is it dangerous to read? 3. Scrapped regex and used `split()`, `.flatMap()`, and `.join()`.

Comment: @zer00ne, Thank you for the elaborate answer. Actually I could not match the elements, this is the only way I have managed to match the text I require TEST with the elements `var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'TEST')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var node=xpathResult.singleNodeValue;`

Comment: Sure no problem but you should add the xpath tag to your question it would help others in the future. Also, if you have the time, post your answer and accept it -- unless you think your problem might be too specific to be useful, I can't tell xpath is Greek to me.